# How do I properly execute code in Pgadmin4?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I've been programming in C++ and Python for a while now and I recently just started learning SQL and PostgreSQL. I like to use Pgadmin4 to write my code but I am a bit confused on writing and executing my code.

If I create a table and then hit the Execute/Refresh button in the Query Tool, Query Editor to check that the table was created successfully and then write some more code like inserting values and such, the next time I hit Execute/Refresh I get an error because it also executes the code I used to create the table and now I get an Error that states table already exists.

Does that mean I have to delete my code that created the table before I write new code? If I have to delete previous code in order to stop things from being created or executed twice, how can I see or edit previous code?

Comment: Try `psql` instead of pgAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

Some clients allow you to highlight and run *selected* code. If you don't select anything, it runs everything.

Normally you'll use both this client and an editor in parallel, working on your SQL in the editor, then copy-pasting it over to run it, adjusting as necessary. This usually means pasting over the old query with a new one, running that, and repeating as necessary.

It helps to save your intermediate work so that you can recreate tables as necessary, or reproduce the steps to get it.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Are there any editors you'd recommend to use this with?

Comment: Whatever you want, so long as it's a code editor and not a word processor, like Notepad but not WordPad. Ideally it has a SQL syntax highlighting feature to help spot mistakes. Popular choices: [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com), [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com), and [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/) among *dozens* of others.

Comment: As indicated psql is always available. It is a command line interface to Postgres. PgAdmin4 (IMHO a peice of junk) does permit executing just the selected code. You can always use multi-line comments to "bypass" the code you do not want run. An  option for DB aware IDE option is DBeaver. It has the option to run *single statement* vs entire script.  Where single statement has a liberal definition of run where cursor is located - even if that is a compile or even as DO block.  Other IDEs for Postgres also have this option.

Comment: @Belayer I'm also disappointed in PgAdmin as PgAdmin3 wasn't terrible and did a lot of things that 4 doesn't even attempt. A huge regression.